# Django-tables2 define custom column on view

Tags: django, dynamic, dry, django-tables2

I want to define a generic django-tables2 Table like this:

```
class GenericTable(tables.Table):
    c1 = tables.TemplateColumn("placeholder")
```

Now, on my views I'd like to do something like that *(warning - pseudocode)*:

```
g=GenericTable() # Don't pass data to the table right now
g.columns[0].verbose_name="Specific name based on view"
g.columns[0].template = "Spefic template based on view"
g=initialize( [...] )
```

Is there a way to do that ?

If that is not possible, is it possible to change the definition of the GenericTable class before initializing it ?

I could define a number of tables with different c1 fields but that wont' be DRY :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in in the init method.... it's the same:

```
class GenericTable(tables.Table):

    def __init__(self, name_based_in_the_view, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GenericTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base_columns['c1'].verbose_name = name_based_in_the_view
```

In your view:

```
g = GenericTable(name_based_in_the_view = "Specific name based on view")
```

Comment: What about the template that will be used to render the column? Is there a way to change that also ?

Comment: It's the same.... you can change every attr access through basecolumns. I didn't write this because I thought that was evident

Comment: What is the name of the "template" attribute  ?

Comment: https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/columns.py#L455